# How to apply complex generated styles with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, styles

Say we generated such string:

```
    background:#6356ff;
background:url(data:image/svg+xml;
base64,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);
background:linear-gradient(top,#6356ff 0%,#75b6ff 100%);
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6356ff',endColorstr='#75b6ff',GradientType=0 );
```

and now we want to apply such complex style to our document html and body. how to perform such thing with jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add it with

```
$('#box').attr('style',str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n7ENn/

Or appending to existing styles should be possible with the following snippet

```
$('#box').attr('style',$('#box').attr('style')+str);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n7ENn/1/

Answer (score 0):

Just put it in a css class and `addClass()`;

```
.cool {
    background:#6356ff;
    background:url(data:image/svg+xml;
    base64,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);
    background:linear-gradient(top,#6356ff 0%,#75b6ff 100%);
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#6356ff',endColorstr='#75b6ff',GradientType=0 );
}

$('#id').addClass('cool');
```

Comment: Shouldn't the actual values be quoted or something? EDIT: Oh wait... it's it's a CSS definition? I believe OP asked for 'generated string' to be applied as CSS...

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.  They have the CSS as a javascript string and I presume they want to know how to apply it via javascript.